# Puppeteer Chromium, disable "Anonymize local IPs exposed by WebRTC"

Tags: testing, webrtc, chromium, puppeteer

I'm trying to run puppeteer tests using Chromium against a local server on `http://localhost:3080/`.

The page is a streaming video over webRTC, but because it's on localhost I'd like the `Anonymize local IPs exposed by WebRTC` from `chrome://flags` to be set to disabled when launching Chromium. *(this would be purely for local testing)*
I pass puppeteer "args" like so:

```
const page = await puppeteer.launch({args: ["...", "..."]});
```

Just can't seem to be able to find the correct flag to pass to args even after going through this [list](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) *(really slow to load)* 
Would anyone have any ideas as to how I can get around this issue or what arg I might be able to pass to Chromium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

--disable-features=WebRtcHideLocalIpsWithMdns
should work.

Comment: ahh didn't realise you could use it straight like that. Worked perfectly thanks :)

Comment: @philipp I did try out but did not work for me with residential/mobile proxies + puppeteer headless: "new" + --disable-features=WebRtcHideLocalIpsWithMdns I tested it on pixel scan and it shows location is spoofed